# Getting UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f12103434d0> In Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am creating. a deep learning model on google colab and I am getting this error: `UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f12103434d0>` I am creating an ASL deep learning model and then I get this error. Can anyone help me solve this issue... Are my images maybe corrupted? hmm... Please help. thanks for the help.

here is my code:

(python file)

```
import random
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
# from keras.utils import np_utils, to_categorical
from keras.preprocessing import image
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir, join
import tensorflow as tf

 

def load_data(container_path='datasets', folders=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39'],
              size=2000, test_split=0.2, seed=0):
    """
    Loads sign language dataset.
    """
    
    filenames, labels = [], []

    for label, folder in enumerate(folders):
        folder_path = join(container_path, folder)
        images = [join(folder_path, d)
                     for d in sorted(listdir(folder_path))]
        labels.extend(len(images) * [label])
        filenames.extend(images)
    
    random.seed(seed)
    data = list(zip(filenames, labels))
    random.shuffle(data)
    data = data[:size]
    filenames, labels = zip(*data)

    
    # Get the images
 
    #x = np.array(filenames).astype('float32')/255
 
    paths_to_tensor(filenames).astype('float32')/255
    # Store the one-hot targets
    y = np.array(labels)

    x_train = np.array(x[:int(len(x) * (1 - test_split))])
    y_train = np.array(y[:int(len(x) * (1 - test_split))])
    x_test = np.array(x[int(len(x) * (1 - test_split)):])
    y_test = np.array(y[int(len(x) * (1 - test_split)):])

    return (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)


 

def path_to_tensor(img_path, size):
    # loads RGB image as PIL.Image.Image type
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(size, size))
    # convert PIL.Image.Image type to 3D tensor
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    # convert 3D tensor to 4D tensor 
    return np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

def paths_to_tensor(img_paths, size=50):
    list_of_tensors = [path_to_tensor(img_path, size) for img_path in img_paths]
    return np.vstack(list_of_tensors)
```

Google Colab Notebook:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(5) 
import tensorflow as tf
# import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
# tf.disable_v2_behavior()
# tf.random.set_seed(2)

#tf.random.set_seed(2)
# tf.set_random_seed(2)
from datasets import sign_language

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline



# Load pre-shuffled training and test datasets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = sign_language.load_data() # error is here
```

Stack trace:

```
    UnidentifiedImageError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c1560e7a4fef> in <module>()
     17 
     18 # Load pre-shuffled training and test datasets
---> 19 (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = sign_language.load_data()
     20 
     21 # print(x_train.shape)

6 frames
/content/datasets/sign_language.py in load_data(container_path, folders, size, test_split, seed)
     36     #x = np.array(filenames).astype('float32')/255
     37 
---> 38     paths_to_tensor(filenames).astype('float32')/255
     39     # Store the one-hot targets
     40     y = np.array(labels)

/content/datasets/sign_language.py in paths_to_tensor(img_paths, size)
     59 
     60 def paths_to_tensor(img_paths, size=50):
---> 61     list_of_tensors = [path_to_tensor(img_path, size) for img_path in img_paths]
     62     return np.vstack(list_of_tensors)
     63 

/content/datasets/sign_language.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     59 
     60 def paths_to_tensor(img_paths, size=50):
---> 61     list_of_tensors = [path_to_tensor(img_path, size) for img_path in img_paths]
     62     return np.vstack(list_of_tensors)
     63 

/content/datasets/sign_language.py in path_to_tensor(img_path, size)
     52 def path_to_tensor(img_path, size):
     53     # loads RGB image as PIL.Image.Image type
---> 54     img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(size, size))
     55     # convert PIL.Image.Image type to 3D tensor
     56     x = image.img_to_array(img)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    312   """
    313   return image.load_img(path, grayscale=grayscale, color_mode=color_mode,
--> 314                         target_size=target_size, interpolation=interpolation)
    315 
    316 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    112                           'The use of `load_img` requires PIL.')
    113     with open(path, 'rb') as f:
--> 114         img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
    115         if color_mode == 'grayscale':
    116             # if image is not already an 8-bit, 16-bit or 32-bit grayscale image

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode, formats)
   3007         warnings.warn(message)
   3008     raise UnidentifiedImageError(
-> 3009         "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
   3010     )
   3011 

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f12103434d0>
```

Comment: Exactly where are you seeing that error?  And, by the way, you are calling `paths_to_tensor`, which returns a tensor, which you then convert to float32 and divide by 255, and you then throw that whole thing away, because you didn't save it in a variable.

Comment: this is where I see the error on `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = sign_language.load_data()`

Comment: That's just the first line.  Please edit your message to post the entire traceback.

Comment: please check the whole stack trace above

Comment: You're grabbing every files in those directories.  Are you sure EVERY file in all of those directories is an image?  And why are you forcing the random seed?  That's not generally productive.

Comment: Yes they are. They are jpg images

Comment: Also, my upload my zip and then an unzip automatically colab generate a _MACOS folder, is it normal?

Comment: That means you're running on MacOS, which puts hidden files in some folders.  That may be the problem.  You need to filter your `images` list after the `listdir` to make sure you only keep the files with a `.jpg` extension.

Comment: Can you show me a snippet on how to do that?

Comment: The easy way is to replace the `images = [join(folder_path...` line with `images = glob.glob(folder_path+'/*.jpg')`.  After adding `import glob`, of course.